# Airflow Callbacks Not Initiating

Tags: python, airflow, slack

I have a yaml file that is processed in DagFactory to create a DAG to be executed in Airflow 2.5.1. It is setup to load a python file and execute a function based on the callbacks for `Start`, `Finish`, and `Failuer` based on [this example](https://github.com/ajbosco/dag-factory/blob/master/examples/example_dag_factory.yml). The python file has these notifications sent to Slack. At this point I am only receiving this message in the logs at the start

```
{cli_action_loggers.py:65} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: [<function default_action_log at 0x7ff073bd19d0>]
```

and this at the end

```
{cli_action_loggers.py:83} DEBUG - Calling callbacks: []
```

I would expect to see the message in the logs but I may be wrong. Also, the notifications do not reach Slack.

Looking for help with either my python code or yaml based on the example on why Airflow will not execute the callback correctly or send to slack.

YAMl

```
dag:
  default_args:
    owner: "me"
    depends_on_past: False
    retries: 0
    retry_dely: datetime.timedelta(minutes=3)
    on_execute_callback_name: slack_notification_start_operator
    on_execute_callback_file: /home/airflow/provider/dags/dependencies/slack_notification.py
    on_success_callback_name: slack_notification_finish
    on_success_callback_file: //home/airflow/provider/dags/dependencies/slack_notification.py
    on_failure_callback_name: slack_notification_failed_callback
    on_failure_callback_file: /home/airflow/provider/dags/dependencies/slack_notification.py
    provide_context: True
    wait_for_downstream: True
```

Slack Python code

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator import SlackWebhookOperator
from slack_sdk.webhook import WebhookClient

SLACK_CONN_ID = "my_slack_connection_id"

def slack_notification_start(**context):
    SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    SLACK_MSG = f"""
        :stopwatch: Airflow DAG initiated.
        *Dag*: {context['task_instance'].dag_id}
        *Execution Time*: {context['execution_date']}
        *Log Url*: {context['task_instance'].log_url}
        """
    slack_notification_start_operator = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_notification_start',
        http_conn_id=SLACK_CONN_ID,
        webhook_token=SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN,
        message=SLACK_MSG,
        username='airflow')
    return slack_notification_start_operator.execute(context=context)

def slack_notification_failed_callback(context):
    SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    current_time = datetime.now()
    SLACK_MSG = f"""
        :red_circle: Task Failed.
        *Task*: {context['task_instance'].task_id}
        *Dag*: {context['task_instance'].dag_id}
        *Failure Time*: {current_time}
        *Log Url*: {context['task_instance'].log_url}
        """
    slack_notification_fail_operator = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_notification_fail',
        http_conn_id=SLACK_CONN_ID,
        webhook_token=SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN,
        message=SLACK_MSG,
        username='airflow')
    return slack_notification_fail_operator.execute(context=context)

def slack_notification_finish(**context):
    SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    current_time = datetime.now()
    SLACK_MSG = f"""
        :white_check_mark: Airflow DAG finished.
        *Dag*: {context['task_instance'].dag_id}
        *Completion Time*: {current_time}
        *Log Url*: {context['task_instance'].log_url}
        """
    slack_notification_finish_operator = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_notification_finish',
        http_conn_id=SLACK_CONN_ID,
        webhook_token=SLACK_WEBHOOK_TOKEN,
        message=SLACK_MSG,
        username='airflow')
    return slack_notification_finish_operator.execute(context=context)
```

Comment: Can you also share the DAG code? It's also probably worthwhile to ensure whatever logic you're using to load the slack notification functions is working (e.g. making sure it works using a Python repl)

Comment: The DAG code is produced by the dagfactory (see example in OP) and then removed once completed. The slack notification works in the manual DAGs we create, the only difference is that in the manual DAGs the slack notification is a task in the DAG and not using the callbacks. @RNHTTR